# Make Android always ask where to save a file on every download

Tags: browser, settings, downloading

Is it possible (as an OS-level setting or somewhere in application properties)?

Maybe every time a user action leads to saving a file some system event is fired and it's possible to write an app for that purpose? Or maybe someone already did it ;)?

Any help'd be really useful as I'm really fed up with digging through `sdcard/download` looking for an md5-string-named file or looking for a folder `super_editor/saves` or even `saves/super_editor` that might be located anywhere.

Comment: [This link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/nGjKpc36vUU) might be relevant.